Query a pandas DataFrame for a Windows path
I need to inventory a network server. I want to save a list of file names, paths, file sizes, and created and accessed dates into a CSV file. Here is my code:
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ME\Documents\INVENTORY.csv")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"S:\XXXXXXXXXXX"):
    for file in files:
        sfullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(sfullpath)
        dftemp = df.query(rf"FullPath == '{sfullpath}'") # Error here
        if len(dftemp.index) == 0:
            try:
                ssize = str(os.stat(sfullpath).st_size)
                ctime = os.stat(sfullpath).st_ctime
                cdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(ctime).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
                atime = os.stat(sfullpath).st_atime
                adate = datetime.fromtimestamp(atime).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
                with open(r"C:\Users\ME\Documents\INVENTORY.csv", 'a') as f:
                    f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"%(sfullpath,file,root,ssize,cdate,adate))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue

My script works until it gets to a file path with a \N in it. I thought that having rf or fr in front of the query string would tell Python to format variables and ignore escape characters, but I still get this error (pardon the redaction):
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    FullPath =='S:\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXX\Nxxxxxxxxx\desktop.ini'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 21-22: malformed \N character escape

Is there a better way to check that a specific file hasn't already been written to the CSV? This server is huge and the script probably won't be able to scan the whole thing in one go. Thanks in advance.

Just to be clarify, since the error text you include doesn't make clear, does the error arise directly from your file or from a trace somewhere inside df.query?

@AlexDuchnowski I didn't include the full traceback because there could be identifying information in there. The traceback stars with dftemp = df.query(rf"FullPath == '{sfullpath}'") then goes through 7 pandas layers before calling ast.parse() which then produces the error shown above.

Pandas documents some issues like this. See the section on 'Backtick quoted variables' in https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html. You might try adding parser='python' to your query or adjusting the engine in the read_csv?

When dealing with file paths I normally will use the forward slash / character instead of the backslash \. The other method is to use two backslashes together \\. So try...
FullPath ='S:/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/Nxxxxxxxxx/desktop.ini'

Or -

FullPath ='S:\\XXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXX\\Nxxxxxxxxx\\desktop.ini'

Edit

When using os.path.join(). I will reference the answer here mixed slashes with os.path.join on windows
os.path.join(root, file).replace("\\","/")


The path string is coming from sfullpath = os.path.join(root, file). I don't have any control over the contents of the string unless I do something like sfullpath.replace("\","/")

I am not sure but would
sfullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
sfullpath = os.path.normpath(sfullpath)
work for you?

Adding sfullpath = os.path.normpath(sfullpath) didn't change anything.

Did you end up trying the sfullpath.replace("\","/")? If it worked let me know. I don't have a recommendation right other than the edit above.
